# PHP Codeigniter asigning controller to a html element

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter and I am wondering how can i add a controller to a html button or div element. I want for example to have a div element which on click to ask for a controller and so on. Tried with a button with a action="controller/function" but couldn't succeed.

Comment: Maybe what you want is an ajax call. Or a direct link to that controller.

Comment: why would `action="...."` automagically do something? It's like spraypainting 'rocket' on to a car and expecting it to fly to the moon... Keywords to search for: 'intro to html', 'intro to javascript', 'ajax', 'javascript onclick', 'codeigniter'

Comment: Button can not have an action property. Please go to learn some basic html first then come to learn php and Codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `site_url()` like this

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controllername/methodname');?>" >Click Me</a>
```

Or direct an anchor

```
<?php echo anchor('controllername/methodname');?>
```

And in the form you can use `form_open()`.

```
<?php echo form_open('controllername/methodname');?>
```

Reference

[URL Helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

And

[Form Helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)